# How to Post data to Volt app?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, voltrb

I've got a use case where I'd like to POST some data to my Volt app, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do it. `app/main/config/routes.rb` doesn't recognize a post method like a Sinatra route.

I also tried a Volt-external class tied into the app via config.ru, and I can POST my data to the same Mongo collection that Volt is using. But that data is not reflected in the app until I refresh the page, which is less than ideal. I was hoping my reactive models would see the change in the DB and reflect that on the front end.

I understand that Volt is in beta, so this feature may not be implemented yet (or even planned for the future). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Long term I'm going to make it so you can route REST requests to Tasks (or possibly another set of classes).  In the short term, using rack is the right way.  I'm in the process of adding a wrapper to the mongo api that knows how to trigger the updates.  Should be out in a day or two, I'll update here when it is.

Comment: you must have looong days :D

Comment: @Ich yea, it took a lot longer than I expected.  Its out in the 0.9.0 pre-release.